# Form Button in Iframe, When Clicked, Load in Parent Window

Tags: javascript, iframe

My page has an iFrame that loads products from an external javascript file.  The products are not links, they are submit input buttons.  Without knowing the url of the button, is it possible to load in the parent window instead of the iframe when clicked?

Please note, I do not have access to change anything within the javascript inside the iframe.

```
<iframe>
    <!-- irrelevant code -->

    <!-- button generated by external javascript -->
    <input class="ssc_lrBuyBtn" onclick="ssc.buyClicked(1,2)" id="ssc_BB_1" value="Buy" type="button">

</iframe>
```

There are no form tags around each of the buttons.  The urls that the buttons call change regularly.  Could I add javascript before or after the iframe to make the buttons open in the parent window?  As of now, I have tried the base tag and a js snippet that is supposed to change the target, however, I think they only work for links, not buttons.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onsubmit="window.opener.location.reload();"
```

might help. Check out this thread: [Refresh Parent Window with JS](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?35326-Javascript-Refresh-Parent-Window)